# dash is missing from Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, unity-dash

I'd rather use Ubuntu Desktop everywhere to keep things simple. Unfortunately I have no choice but to deploy Ubuntu Server on a cloud VM. This [tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/remote-desktop/install-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04) from the cloud provider instructs that to make the system like a desktop do the following.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon metacity nautilus gnome-terminal
```

The `~/.vnc/xstartup` file should look like the following.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey 
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
```

After making those preparations the desktop is still quite different from what I am familiar with. There is a logo for the `dash` but it doesn't give me a search capability that I am familiar with. How do I get the `dash` search working?